# How do I make user data persist from one page to another page without a database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form on one page of my ruby on rails app that takes user entry via a text input field. When the user clicks save and continue I want the next page to display the text entered by the user on the previous page.

```
      <div class="test-group">
        <label class="test_label" for="full-name">
          Enter full name
        </label>
        <form action="clientname" method="POST">
          <input class = "test-input" type="text" name="name" id="client-name-entry">
          <br/>
        </form>
      </div>
```

On the next linked page, accessed via a "Save and Continue" button I have the following:

```
<div class="column-two-thirds">
  <h1 class="test-label">Your name is <%= clientname %></h1>
  <button  type="submit" class="start-button" >Continue</button>
</div>
```

How do I get the name to display on the second page, the above gives me the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `clientname'
```

I know I need something in my application_controller but I am not sure what that is. Currently it is:

```
def input_page
  @client = clientname
end
```

I need to avoid using a database for now thats why I am trying to just get the data to persist from page to page right now.

Answer (score 1):

persistence like this, without a database, and server side, can only be done with sessions. For example, once the first page is submitted, you could do:

`session[:name] = params[:name]`

and then in the form on the next page you could use that:

```
<div class="column-two-thirds">
  <h1 class="test-label">Your name is <%= session[:name] %></h1>
  <button  type="submit" class="start-button" >Continue</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Or cookies, yes?

Comment: @jvillian You got me on that one. I always forget the biscuits.

Comment: For rails sessions you have multiple options but I believe the most common one is actually the cookie store. Here all session data gets encoded (or encrypted if needed) and stored in the clients browser for later reference. It will be sent with every request so you can access the previously set data in a later request.
So the session approach and a plain cookie are not too different.